# about staking on port.onflow.org

Tags: validation, delegates, staking

I'm writing to you because I've been delegating my tokens for over a year now. Last week I saw a request for destacking on one of my validators (I've never asked to withdraw my tokens) and today when I logged in I can't see the validator and I haven't received my tokens on my portfolio flow.
if someone could be so kind as to answer me and reassure me
should I just wait? (I've never destacked a token before)
thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.